# Menu dropdpwn não funciona no touch

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, touch

Estou com o seguinte problema fiz este [site](http://agenciafront.com.br/passebem/) porem acessando ele no celular e clicando no menu ele expande porem a um dropown na aba o que oferecemos e quando clico em um link ele não funciona ele simplesmente seleciona o link debaixo mais vale lembrar que na versão desktop funciona normalmente o erro está quando uso um dispositivo mobile e ultilizo touch estou usando bootstrap existe alguma maneira de resolver isso

Comment: No touch não existe  `mouseover` então é óbvio que não irá funcionar. Seria bom colocar um menu diferenciado que irá ser exibido em dispositivos de toque, possivelmente um menu sanfona ou um select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta adicionar esse meta no cabeçalho do seu código:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, tenta achar o arquivo bootstrap.min.js, e achar o texto:

```
"ontouchstart"
```

e substituir por:

```
"disable-ontouchstart"
```

[Como diz nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440942)

Comment: O meta já está no código.